# A question about Vectors

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, notation

Consider a vector $a = (x,y)$.

I know that this notation $|a|$ means the magnitude of the vector which is calculated by $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.

But what does this notation $\|a\|$ mean?

Thank you.

Comment: It often means the same thing.

Comment: Did you write the same thing twice or have I missed something??

Comment: Just had a quiz where I had an equation with both of these, I don't believe they mean the same thing.

Comment: Then ask your instructor?

Comment: It's an online course unfortunately

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16163/how-are-norms-different-from-absolute-values

Comment: You have an online course with no instructor?  That is disturbing.

Comment: Thank you @Äres, much appreciated.

Comment: @user2373804 You're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Like much of notation, it could depend on your instructor's personal style.

But, in general, the mapping $v\mapsto||v||$ refers to an arbitrary [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) on the space.  The go-to example for norms is magnitude or absolute value, so usually we refer to it as $|v|$.  But if the problem you're talking about had a different norm function under consideration, that could explain why there was both.

Or it was a typo.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, much appreciated