# Inner Product of Absolute Values Equals Absolute value of Inner Product of Absolute Values

Tags: complex-analysis

Please note, this seems very simple. But I am unable to prove this.

**Main Doubt:**

$$
\left|\left(\left|x\right|,\left|y\right|\right)\right|=\left(\left|x\right|,\left|y\right|\right)
$$

Here, $x$ and $y$ are complex functions and $(x,y)$ is the inner product.
$|x| = \left(x\overline{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is the absolute value of $x$. Absolute value is defined as the non-negative square root of a complex number multiplied by its conjugate. (Using the definition of absolute value from Rudin Principles of Mathematical Analysis: Definition 1.32)

From my limited experience with the inner product, I have seen it defined differently depending on the space. But the above should hold in all spaces I presume (just a hunch, could be wrong) ? So without using a specific definition of inner product restricted to a particular space. Are we able to show the above?

**Related Question:** Perhaps, the real question is whether the inner product of real numbers is always a real number? That is, if the $\left(\left|x\right|,\left|y\right|\right)$ is a real number since $|x|$ and $|y|$ are real numbers.  If this is true then, $$\left(\left|x\right|,\left|y\right|\right)=\overline{\left(\left|x\right|,\left|y\right|\right)}$$

This gives,

$$
\left|\left(\left|x\right|,\left|y\right|\right)\right|=\left\{ \left(\left|x\right|,\left|y\right|\right)\overline{\left(\left|x\right|,\left|y\right|\right)}\right\} ^{\frac{1}{2}}=\left(\left|x\right|,\left|y\right|\right)
$$

**Another confusion or question:**
Can we say that $x$ and $y$ are vectors which would suggest that absolute value is defined for any vector in a complex vector space?

I am using the notation from Rudin Real and Complex Analysis (RCA).

Thanks in advance. Happy to delete this question if too simple etc.

Comment: What's your definition of absolute value of a complex function? If you mean a norm on complex value function, then your question 1 is true since norm map a vector to non-negative real number

Comment: Please note we can define the absolute value  as the non-negative square root of a complex number multiplied by its conjugate. (Using the definition from Rudin Principles of Mathematical Analysis: Definition 1.32)  $|x| = (x\overline{x})^{1/2}$

Comment: @wer Using the above definition might not need norm or other advanced topics perhaps?

Comment: you say "x and y are complex functions" so your definition of abs(x(t)) is  a real valued function $g(t)=x(t) \bar{x} (t) $ over some set? So you use two inner product here. One is over function, one is over two real numbers.  But that's fine. Just take Abs(x(t)) as a non negative number on fixed t.

Comment: Your equality follows from the fact that inner product has to be positive by the positive of $|x|=(x,x)$. Additionally, inner product on $f(x,y) :R \times R \to R $ is in fact of the form $f(x,y)=axy$  in your case , where $a$ is a real number. (you can prove it with 3 properties of inner product) By positive definitness of inner product, it has to be $a>0$

Comment: @wer My understanding is that the inner product is a complex number. So unless we specify more properties, we cannot consider a complex number as positive or negative right?

Comment: your equality for question 1 is natrually right, No additional properties are needed. You may take a look at the defination of inner product and norm derived from inner product for more clear understanding.  Norm is not very advanced topic,  it is a generalization of absolute value. You can try to learn it for a better understanding.

Comment: Linking Related Question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16163/how-are-norms-different-from-absolute-values